# Java (SQL Like) and Shell script Problem to run 2 parameters

Tags: java, shell, hadoop

I have a java class Filter2 and I want to run it with a shell script run2.sh. The issue is I dont know how I am able to input 2 parameters ($1 and $2) in the shell scripting.

```java
public class Filter2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        conf.set("limit", otherArgs[0]);
    conf.set("limit2", otherArgs[1]);//added here

    Job job = new Job(conf, "Distributed Filter");
    job.setJarByClass(Filter2.class);
    job.setMapperClass(FilterMapper.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0); // Set number of reducers to zero
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

 public static class FilterMapper
     extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

     private final static IntWritable counter = new IntWritable(0);
     private Text word = new Text();
     private Integer total;

     private Integer limit;
     private Integer limit2;//added here
     public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
             ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());

     limit = Integer.parseInt( context.getConfiguration().get("limit") );
     limit2 = Integer.parseInt( context.getConfiguration().get("limit2") );

     while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
         word.set(itr.nextToken());
             total = Integer.parseInt(itr.nextToken());//added here

         if ((total > limit)&&(total<limit2))//added here    
         { counter.set( total );
           context.write(word, counter); }
     }
     }
 }

}
```

run2.sh

```sh
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar Filter2.jar Filter2 $1 sales.txt /user/solution2/
```

I want to run my java with the shell script in the terminal "./run.sh 45 50" but I am not able to put 2 input parameters. How can I modify my shell script to enable this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass more than one argument to the script the name of the variable just gets incremented.

```
#/bin/bash
echo "arg1: $1"
echo "arg2: $2"
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar Filter2.jar Filter2 $1 $2 sales.txt /user/solution2/
```

If you call this script with

```
./run.sh 45 50
```

you will see

```
arg1: 45
arg2: 50
```

on the console (plus whatever your hadoop command does). Notice the `$2` in the hadoop line. This is the second script argument. Move it to the location where it is needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!
I have tried to use your solution and I have been met with another error.
Im having the exception that says FileAlreadyExistsException. Would you happen to know why this is happening? Could it be due to a possible syntax error on my side?

Comment: The name of the exception already says it all. Some part of your application is trying to create a file that already exists. The exception should contain the file name in the message. Move that file somewhere else and try again.